# How to Cancel a file upload to AWS S3 using AWS Amplify IOS Library?

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am developing an ios app with AWS Amplify supporting my backend.  I am able to upload files to S3 but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to cancel a currently executing upload ([documentation here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/ios)).  Please can someone advise?

This is what I use to upload:

```
import UIKit
import AWSAppSync
import Amplify
import AWSMobileClient
import AmplifyPlugins


let dataString = "My Data"
let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)!
Amplify.Storage.uploadData(key: "ExampleKey", data: data, 
progressListener: { progress in
    print("Progress: \(progress)")
}, resultListener: { event in
    switch event {
    case .success(let data):
        print("Completed: \(data)")
    case .failure(let storageError):
        print("Failed: \(storageError.errorDescription). \(storageError.recoverySuggestion)")
})
})
```

Comment: Hey johnDoe, did you find a solution for this. I'm having the same problem.